# Best way to get velocity/speed in android

Tags: android

Having all the new sensors (LINEAR_ACCELERATION, ROTATION_VECTOR) what's the best way to get the real speed of the phone (supposing I can't use GPS's method getSpeed().

What's the most common usage of those two sensors along with quaternions?

Thanks! Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

What are you thinking on when you are speaking abaut the "speed of your phone" ?
If I understand, you are interested on the speed when you are in the car with your phone or something like this?

For this, you have to use your gps sensor because it is the only one which can give you the speed. The linear acceleration will provide you the acceleration and not the speed, which is different.

If you are interested in how to use the gps sensor, i can give you an exemple of my code.

Comment: You can integrate the acceleration to get the velocity for example, that was what I was talking about, but I want to know the best and more efficient way to do it...